# What is the name of this part? (motorcycle)

Tags: motorcycle, design, cagiva

[image]

What is the name of this part??
I searched exhaust guard but it's not right... I want to buy one for my motorcycle (same model - 2003 Cagiva Planet 125)

Answer (score 4):

It's called the "Lower Fairing". It can be seen in the following image:

Part Number:

- 800085775 - Lower Fairing, LH (#19)
- 800085774 - Lower Fairing, RH (#20)

[image: Image copied from oemmotorparts.com]

Comment: In Aus/NZ it would also commonly be called a 'bellypan'